# How to update Cookie into headers in cy.request in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

When i make a cy.request, the cookie does not update into headers. I tried to clear the cookie before calling cy.setCookie but still getting a different cookie value

```
 putCallAdmin(endpoint, requestBody) {
    let cookie;
    cy.getCookie("Cookie")
      .should("have.property", "value", cookieToken)
      .then((c) => {=
        cookie = c;
      });

    cy.request({
      method: "PUT",
      url: endpoint,
      headers: {
        Cookie: cookie,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: requestBody,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((data) => {
      this.printLogs(data.body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code you provided is that the `cy.getCookie("Cookie")` command is asynchronous and returns a promise. So the `let cookie` variable is not being set until the promise is resolved. By the time your `cy.request` is called, `cookie` still has the initial value of `undefined`.

To resolve this, you need to move the `cy.request` call inside the .then callback function, so that it is only executed after the `cy.getCookie` promise is resolved and the `cookie` variable has been set.

```
putCallAdmin(endpoint, requestBody) {
  cy.getCookie("Cookie")
    .should("have.property", "value", cookieToken)
    .then((c) => {
      cy.request({
        method: "PUT",
        url: endpoint,
        headers: {
          Cookie: c.value,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: requestBody,
        failOnStatusCode: false,
      }).then((data) => {
        this.printLogs(data.body);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried this solution but it didnt work.. it doesnt show the value